# What's the difference between "Wohnsitz" and "Wohnort"

Tags: difference

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/) tells the following

> **Wohnsitz**: Ort, an dem jemand seine Wohnung hat
>
> **Wohnort**: Ort, an dem jemand seinen Wohnsitz hat

Is it supposed to be the same now?

Comment: Was lässt Dich zweifeln?

Answer (score 19):

Well, details.

**Wohnort** has a coarser scope than *Wohnsitz* in my experience. *Wohnort* is primarily the city where someone lives, but *may* mean address (City+Street+etc.).

**Wohnsitz** on the other hand is bureaucracy-speak for address, but may also refer to the very building itself (usually upper-class, think Villas, Chalets, ..).

So the terms are very closely related, with a big shared kernel of meaning, but they also have subtle differences which makes them non-interchangeable in some contexts.

Edit: The problem with the Duden definition as replicated in the question is that two different meanings of *Ort* are used: For the *Wohnsitz* definition the "location" meaning is used, and for the *Wohnort* definition the "city, village, town" meaning is used. So one could actually resolve *Wohnort* to "City/Village/Town where someone's (location where someone's dwelling is) is".

Answer (score 5):

There are two differences between *Wohnort* (literal translation: 'locality of living') and *Wohnsitz* (literal translation: 'seat of living'). The first concerns the level of detail implied:

- A person's *Wohnort* almost invariably is just the locality (city, town or village) where they live.
- A person's *Wohnsitz* is usually a complete address.

If you just want to indicate the *Wohnort* while using the word *Wohnsitz*, the most standard way is using the preposition *in*: "Dagobert Duck hat seinen Wohnsitz *in* Entenhausen." Some people probably drop it. That's non-standard, but much less so than including a street address under *Wohnort* would be.

The second difference is that, unlike the plain and normal word *Wohnort*, *Wohnsitz* is primarily a bureaucratic term that has a very precise definition. Or more precisely one in Germany and a similar one in Austria. (I don't know about the situation in Switzerland.) A person can have several *Wohnsitze*, in which case one of them is the *Hauptwohnsitz* and the others (rarely more than one) are *Nebenwohnsitze*. This should become clearer from the following discussion:

(Read the following details only if you love absurd bureaucracy or if you are planning to live in a German-speaking country.)

Your *Wohnsitz* is the address where you live - regularly and in a non-temporary manner, and where you consequently have to register with the authorities so that the state always knows where to look for you. (In case you owe someone money, or they want to deport you, or whatever.) In principle everybody must have one. It's OK for homeless people to register a place where they don't actually live as *Wohnsitz*, so long as the person or organisation there agrees, they can usually be contacted via that address, and it's at the locality where they spend most of the year. This is important because a *Wohnsitz* is a prerequisite for a bank account (with it, banks *have* to give you one), and a bank account is a prerequisite for certain social benefits. Also, a German living in South America or Australia and returning once a year for a week to stay with his or her parents, may still have a *Wohnsitz* there. As it is the only one, it will be the *Hauptwohnsitz*. Austrian bureaucracy has a sligthtly different point of view that takes into account other countries. Consequently, if our hypothetical German also spends 2 months every year in Austria with his girlfriend and another 2 months at the other end of Austria with her and her parents, then in German bureaucracy he will have a *Hauptwohnsitz* in Germany (and other countries don't matter), and in Austrian bureaucracy he will have a *Hauptwohnsitz* on another continent and possibly 2 *Nebenwohnsitze* in Austria.

I am not completely sure what happens when someone has more German (or Austrian) *Wohnsitze* than *Wohnorte*, e.g. lives at two addresses at opposite ends of Berlin. I think most bureaucrats don't really care about this so long as you don't try to argue that you couldn't attend your trial for treason because the letter went to the other end of the city, where you haven't been in months even though it's formally your *Hauptwohnsitz*. Since the choice of *Hauptwohnsitz* may have a financial effect for the citizen and for the localities involved, I would assume that there are rules designed to prevent splitting the time you live at the same *Wohnort* throughout the year (which is often relatively easy to prove if you have a normal job) evenly over so many addresses that the few weeks you spend in some remote location every year are enough to make your only address there your *Hauptwohnsitz*.

But most people have a city where they actually live most of the year - their *Wohnort* -, and their only address in that city, which according to law is their *(Haupt-)Wohnsitz*, has in fact been registered as such.

Comment: Was Deutschland angeht, ist die Darstellung der juristischen („bürokratischen“) Begriffe nicht korrekt; du vermischt _Wohnsitz_ (Begriff des bürgerlichen Rechts) und _Wohnung_ (Begriff des Melderechts). Darüber hinaus gibt es auch noch den _Aufenthalt_ und den _Lebensmittelpunkt_. Eine _Wohnung_ ist ein „umschlossene[r] Raum, der zum Wohnen oder Schlafen benutzt wird“. Wenn man genau eine hat, ist das die _alleinige Wohnung_ (nicht Hauptwohnung, nicht Hauptwohnsitz!), andernfalls ist eine davon die _Hauptwohnung_ und alle anderen sind _Nebenwohnungen_. (wird fortgesetzt)

Comment: Ein _Wohnsitz_ ist dagegen ein Ort (politische Gemeinde), an dem sich jemand ständig niedergelassen hat. Man kann mehrere Wohnsitze haben, sie werden aber nicht in Haupt- und Neben- unterteilt. Bei einer _Wohnung_ hat man nicht zwangsläufig auch einen _Wohnsitz_, weil es bei diesem auf die Dauerhaftigkeit ankommt. Wer sich etwa eine _Wohnung_ in X nimmt mit der Absicht, dort vier bis fünf Jahre lang zu studieren und dann sofort wieder wegzuziehen, für den ist X kein _Wohnsitz_.

Comment: @chirlu: Aus juristischer Sicht ist dieser Einwand sicher vollkommen korrekt. Der Sprachgebrauch von Juristen hat mich in meiner Antwort allerdings gar nicht interessiert. Mir scheint, dass hier lediglich das Melderecht auf das Wort "Wohnung" ausgewichen ist, um die Verwirrung zu verhindern, die sich ergäbe, wenn ein und dasselbe Wort doppelt belegt wäre, also mit subtil abweichenden zivil- und melderechtlichen Definitionen. Im österr. Meldegesetz ist *Wohnsitz* die offizielle Bezeichnung. Mindestens in meiner deutschen Heimatregion ist es immerhin die umgangssprachliche für gemeldete Wohnung.

Comment: @chirlu: Gerade wegen des abweichenden allgemeinsprachlichen Gebrauchs dürfte Folgendes im Wikipedia-Artikel zur "Wohnsitz (Deutschland)" stehen: "Im Melderechtsrahmengesetz sowie in den dazugehörigen Meldegesetzen der Länder kommt dieser Begriff nicht vor. Hier wird zur Abgrenzung von anderen Rechtsgebieten ausschließlich der Wohnungs-Begriff verwendet."

Answer (score 3):

Der Wohnort, wohnhaft, die Wohnadresse, und das Domizil einer Person sind geografische Ortsbestimmungen des Wohnsitzes.
Der Wohnsitz ist der juristische Bestimmungsort einer dort wohnenden und lebenden Person. Er braucht nicht mit dem Wohnort etc. identisch zu sein sondern wird durch das Recht bestimmt. z.B. ein deutscher Wohnsitz ist die Wohnstätte eines Deutschen in Deutschland und auch im Ausland solange dieser die Staatsangehörigkeit des Landes seines Wohnortes nicht erworben hat. (Ein deutscher Wohnsitz in Italien ist also kein rechtlicher italienischer Wohnsitz). Im Schweizerischen ZGB Art. 22 wird der Wohnsitz einer Person genau bestimmt. Da wird genau bestimmt wann sich der Wohnsitz rechtlich ändert.